# Java Clients and Salesforce.com

Tags: java, html5

There have been many articles about browsers such as Chrome and Firefox eliminating support for plugins like Java.  How will this effect Salesforce.com users that connect using Java?

Is HTML5 access an option?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any specific scenario's or functionality in mind ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anybody who is using Java to connect to Salesforce.com would be using an API to work this connection (for example the Force.com IDE is Eclipse based which uses the Metadata API via Java) which would never be completely removed by Salesforce barring a massive change in corporate strategy and a better way to connect devices and systems than APIs.

The articles will be more referring to the replacement of Java Applets (and similarly Flash) which were used by organisations for many years to deliver content on a website. Chrome and Firefox (along with others) are working hard to implement the newer web technologies such as HTML5 to allow richer content in web pages for everyone.

You can already use HTML5 with Salesforce via Visualforce, you just need a compliant browser (Firefox, Chrome, Opera etc.) that supports the HTML5 specification details you wish to use.

In summary:

TL;DR

It sounds like you are an existing Salesforce customer using a Java client to access Salesforce from your desktop. Salesforce will still have the API that your client is using available and as such you should not be concerned about the move of in browser technology towards the use of things like HTML5 as it will not impact your use case.